# finite expected value for a generated binary number.

Tags: probability, probabilistic-method

A binary number that is generated in the following way:
We start with zero bits (which is considered a valid representation of 0), In each step the probability to stop generating is p (and the probability to continue is 1-p), In addition, in each step the probability to generate "1" is q (and the probability to generate "0" is 1-q). all the probabilities are independent of each other. 
I need to find for which values of p,q the expected value of the generated number is finite.

This is a question in probabilistic method, my initial approach was to use the linearity of expectation but I could not get very far.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hint: The $n$th bit is generated with probability $(1-p)^n$ and is $1$ with probability $q$ hence the expected value of the generated number is $$\sum_nq(1-p)^n2^n.$$

Comment: Isn't that the expected value of the nth bit only and not the entire number? would the correct be a sum over n of the sum you posted?

Comment: The $n$th bit is generated with probability $(1-p)^n$. Its expected value conditionally on the fact that it is generated is $q2^n$. Ergo.

Comment: @user3208617: If you've figured it out, you could post your answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered.